# Rails left join with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, left-join

I have users, problems, and attempts which is a join table between users and problems. I'm looking to show an index of all the problems along with the current user's most recent attempt for each, if they have one.

I've tried four things to get a left join with conditions and none of them have worked.

The naive approach is something like...

```
@problems = Problem.enabled
@problems.each do { |prob|
  prob.last_attempt = prob.attempts
                          .where(user_id: current_user.id)
                          .last
end
```

This gets all the problems and the attempts I want but is N+1 queries. So...

```
@problems = Problem.enabled
                   .includes(:attempts)
```

This does the left join (or the equivalent two queries) getting all the problems but also all the attempts, not just those for the current user. So...

```
@problems = Problem.enabled
                   .includes(:attempts)
                   .where(attempts: {user_id: current_user.id})
```

This gets only those problems that the current user has already attempted.
So...

```
//problem.rb
has_many :user_attempts, 
         -> (user) { where(user_id: user.id) }, 
         class_name: 'Attempt'

//problem_controller.index
@problems = Problem.enabled
                   .includes(:user_attempts, current_user)
```

And this gives an error message from rails saying joins with instance 
arguments are not supported.

So I'm stuck. What is the best way to do this? Is Arel the right tool? Can I skip active record and just get back a JSON blob? Am I just being dumb?

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687535/rails-includes-association-with-condition-in-left-join) but I'd need a argument to the joined scope which isn't supported. And I'm hoping rails added something in last couple years.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to use raw sql. It's ugly and a security risk but I didn't find better.

```
results = Problem.connection.exec_query(%(
    SELECT *
    FROM problems
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * 
    //etc.
    )
))
```

And then manipulating the results array in memory.